# Empty stream with webSocketClientFlow

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a graphdsl, where for some reason after executing `webSocketClientFlow`'s `Flow`, I get an empty stream. The error message on the `run` future is:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty stream
```

The graph looks like this:

```
val loginMessage = Flow[LoginCommand].map(data => {
    TextMessage(data.toJsonString())
}).named("Converting Login to Message").log("LoginMessage")
val exasolAnnounce = http
    .webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest(socketUrl))
        .named("ExasolAnnounceLogin")
        .log("SendAnnounce")

val announceResponse = builder.add(Flow[Message].map(data =>
    LoginCommand.Response.extract(data)
).named("Building Response").log("AnnouncementResponse"))

import GraphDSL.Implicits._

Source.single(new LoginCommand) ~> loginMessage ~> exasolAnnounce ~> announceResponse
```

The last `DEBUG` logs are:

```
[DEBUG] [09/11/2018 09:53:43.328] [TestSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://TestSystem/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Connection established to [192.168.56.2:8563]
[DEBUG] [09/11/2018 09:53:43.346] [TestSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] [akka.stream.Log(akka://TestSystem/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [SendAnnounce] Upstream finished.
[DEBUG] [09/11/2018 09:53:43.346] [TestSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] [akka.stream.Log(akka://TestSystem/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [AnnouncementResponse] Upstream finished.
```

So it seems to me, like it connects to the Websocket but for some reason does not provide a result. Can anyone shed some light where the problem is or how I can trace this further?

---

**EDIT 1**:

Tested with *ws://echo.websocket.org* and then the stream processes as expected.
Not sure how I can further debug Server behavior.

Comment: From the information you are providing it would seem to be that the server is closing the websocket without any data. You may need to give more information about the server.

Comment: Problem is the server is pretty much a black box. Is there any tracing available to support that hypopethis? Or is there a way to force `webSocketClientFlow` to fail if there is no data?

Answer (score 0):

Found, that our Firewall was closing the connection.